# php if username exist in database increase username by one

Tags: php, mysql

I am a bit stuck with my code.

I am practising and would like to achive the following.

Before an user sign up, i want to check the users username exists, if exists than increase the name by one.

So my logic works like this. User gives his/her first and last name, generates an username based on that.

**function**

```
function unique_name($first_name, $last_name) {

$username = strtolower($first_name.'.'.$last_name)

$check = mysqL_query(" SELECT username WHERE username = '".$username."' ");

    if(count($check == 1)) {
        $i = 2;
        foreach($check as $user) {
            return $user['username'].$i;
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        return $username;
    }
}

$username = unique_name($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name']);
// saveing the increased username
```

So actually the script should check if the generated unique username exsits if exsits increase, and encrease it even if it exsits with a number

**example**

Tom Anderson signs up, username will be tom.anderson, saved as tom anderson

Second Tom Anderson signs up, username will be tom.anderson, it already exists, save the new one as tom.anderson2.

The third user signs up he is tom anderson too, username tom.anderson* exsits twice, increase to tom.anderson3.

So i dont have a problem checking if the user exsits and saveing it, my problem is, how to increase every username if exist?

I am not asking anybody to write this for me i am nust looking for a hint

Thank you

**EDIT**

Thank you for the replies but this does not work

```
if(count($check) == 1) {
    $i = 2;
    foreach($check as $user) {
        return $user['username'].count($check);
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    return $username;
}
```

This only check the username with out a number, so if username tom.anderson exists it increases to tom.anderson1 but if tom.anderson1 exists too it wont increase to tom.anderson2

Comment: capitalizing the L in `mysql_*` doesnt make it un-deprecated, also use prepared statements you have vulnerabilities, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you have something that just appends the `count` of the rows returned, unless it's 0?

```
if(count($check) > 0) {
   return $user['username'].count($check);
} else {
    return $username;
}
```

change the SQL:

```
" SELECT username WHERE username LIKE '".$username."%' "
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, sorry maybe i wasnt clear, my problem is with this is so if username tom.anderson exists it increases to tom.anderson1 but if tom.anderson1 exists too it wont increase to tom.anderson2, so if you could give me an example for this i would be really happy if its not a big request

Comment: You also need to change your SQL query, youre only selecting the exact match, you need to use a like statement with a wildcard at the end of your variable

Comment: @Side i made an edit to the answer, see what that does for you, as soon as its excepted anyways

Comment: from your example in the question: first tom anderson is tom.a..n, second is tom.a..n2, third is tom.a..n3? Can you please give a clearer example?

Comment: the best example what i can add, i would like to build a functionality similar to facebook, there if someone signs up with the same username as someone else has, it genereates an username form first last name, and always increases it by one if there are matches

Comment: @Side this answer should do just that, let me explain a little more in depth, basically this new query will find everything that is like your initial variable PLUS everything like it with an alternative ending, I.E. johndoe1. then this script will take the total count and add that to the end, WHICH WILL WORK BECAUSE the initial return will be johndoe without a number.

-@sash no problem :)

Comment: yes now i see how stupid i was, thanks for your help and sorry for my dumb question and for holding you up, and thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to give like this

```
if(count($check) == 1) {
    $i = 2;
    foreach($check as $user) {
        return $user['username'].count($check);
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    return $username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add new field into user table, and called it base_username.
Them fetch count rows with given username, and increase every username on count found
Something like this

```
`function unique_name($first_name, $last_name) {
    $unique_name = $username = strtolower($first_name.'.'.$last_name)
    $cnt = get_row(" SELECT COUNT(*) from `users`  WHERE base_username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1 ");
    if($cnt){
        $unique_name = $username . $cnt + 1;
    }
    return $unique_name;
}`
```